# Cleaning outlook of data

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2003

I started migrating an outlook user to their new computer before it was time, and got the outlook data moved over. Due to other issues, the user then had to keep on using outlook on the old computer. Now it is time for the user to start using outlook on the new computer. Her data on the new computer is now old,  I need to make sure the user has the outlook data from the old computer.

So how I see it is that I need to wipe the outlook data from the new computer. Any idea how to do this?

Bonus question: In the future, how do I best transfer a user's outlook data to a new outlook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close Outlook, then go to Control Panel → Mail, and use this dialog to delete an existing profile, then create a new profile. The Microsoft knowledge base has [an article describing how to do this in detail](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829918).

The best way to migrate a user's data is not to do it all. Use Exchange if you have it, or use IMAP for email and CalDAV for calendars. Then when you need to use a new computer, just set up the accounts and all the data will download automatically.

If this isn't an option, you can move the user's PST file to the new computer. Microsoft has these two articles that might help with the process:

- [Move your Outlook data file to another location](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/move-your-outlook-data-file-to-another-location-HA001112480.aspx)
- [How to manage.pst files in Outlook 2007, in Outlook 2003, and in Outlook 2002](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287070)